# Can more than one scss be used for one SPFx Web Part?

Tags: spfx, scss-mixins

I am new to The SharePoint Framework (SPFx). I am trying to convert old Content Type Web Part into SPFx Web Part. Earlier we have used multiple css files and included into html page. But for SPFx Web Part, I got stuck for how to use more than one scss for one Web Part. I searched but found suggestions on how to give give names of scss for your Web Part but no where i found like it allows only one scss or something.

So i would like to know whether it is possible to have multiple scss file for one web part or not? And if yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be quite easy to accomplish. Just add a new `.module.scss` file to your solution and reference it with a unique identifier.

Example:

```
import styles from './Existing.module.scss'; // this is the one you already have
import additionalStyles from './Example.module.scss'; // your new module
```

Then you can reference these like `<div className={additionalStyles.awesomeClass} />`